# How to check if Azure Service bus in another region is working using Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-monitoring

I'm creating a ping function using azure functions that needs to check if a service bus in another region is operating so it can update the status of the whole system (two regions). What is the best way to check the status of the other service bus \ topics in the other service bus?

I found this code which I could adapt to GetTopic() instead of the Queue:

```
string connectionString = "connection string";
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var queueDescription = namespaceManager.GetQueue("queue name");
var status = queueDescription.Status;
```

However, it has been recommended that this library (WindowsAzure.ServiceBus) has been updated to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus and I can't find a similar way to do this in the newer library.

Please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.queueproperties.status?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: What would be the code to access that property after creating a ServiceBusClient?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ServiceBusAdministrationClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient?view=azure-dotnet) from Package 'Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus v7.8.1' can be used.

[ServiceBusAdministrationClient.GetQueueAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient.getqueueasync?view=azure-dotnet) returns the QueueProperties incl. Status:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.queueproperties.status?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-administration-queueproperties-status

`public Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration.EntityStatus Status { get; set; }`

> The current status of the queue (Enabled / Disabled).

```cs
ServiceBusAdministrationClient serviceBusAdministrationClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient();

var status = await serviceBusAdministrationClient.GetQueueAsync("myQueue").Status;
```